How to diagnose inaccessibility of ad-hoc web server on local network
What tools / strategies might help me diagnose why an ad-hoc web server is not accessible on the local network?

I'm trying to run a minimal, temporary, ad-hoc web server to share some resource on the local network only, using utilities such as

httplz
trunk serve
... etc. etc.

The network is run by a FritzBox 5490, and the device serving the resources can be pinged and sshed from other machines on the local network via all of

myserver.fritz.box
192.168.178.129
192.168.178.188

and probably some IPv6 addresses on top of that.
On the server, I can access the served resources by typing any of the following1  into the URL bar of a web browser, or passing it as an argument to wget:

(localhost:8080)
(127.0.0.1:8080)
myserver.fritz.box:8080
192.168.178.129:8080
192.168.178.188:8080

1 [without any prefix and prefixed with http:// but not when prefixed with https://]
None of these (not surprising for the first two) work on other machines on the network.
Web servers running on some other devices on this network are accessible, including

a printer
some Devolo PowerLANs
Hue lightbulbs
etc.

In case the problem is related to port 80 being special (unblocked by default?) I tried serving on port 80 instead of 8080, but still no joy.
What can I do to understand what is preventing access to the served resources from other machines on the local network?

Summary

Things that work:

the served content is accessible via the public addresses, on the server itself, when served on port

8080
80


the server is pingable and sshable from other devices on the network
other devices on the network serve web pages on port 80, without any special permission to do this having been given on the FritzBox


Things that don't work:

accessing the served pages from other devices on the network, when served on port

8080
80






Try to telnet to the server on port 80.
If it can't connect, then either:

the web-server is not listening on all interfaces
access to the listening port is blocked by a firewall

If you can connect to the machine, on the port, then the issue is with the web-server itself not responding correctly.

telnet times out. Does the fact that using 192.168.178.{188,129} on the server itself work, not indicate that the server is listening on non-loopback interfaces? It works when I run httplz with --address 0.0.0.0 but not 127.0.0.1. Which is why I suspect a firewall ... Ah, OK, found it. Yes, it was a firewall.
